# Write a program that reads a string of characters including punctuation and writes what was read but with the punctuation removed

Tags: c++, string, c++11, reference

Here's my attempt at it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s("hello world!..!.");
   for (auto &c : s)
       if(!ispunct(c))
       {
           cout<<s;
       }
}
```

Here's the output

hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.
hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.hello world!..!.
hello world!..!.

Here's another attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s("hello world!..!.");
   for (auto &c : s)
       if(!ispunct(c))
       {
           cout<<c;
       }
}
```

This gives the correct output (i.e : hello world)

Why won't `cout<<s;` give me the correct output? After all `c` is a reference, so any changes to `c` would also apply to `s`. Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: `cout << s` prints the whole string on each iteration, `cout << c` only prints the current character. References do not have much to do with this.

Comment: But isn't the whole string only hello world after the loop for elimination of punctuation is run?

Comment: @user2474562 Remove the `if` in either cases and see what is printed each time in the loop. Also, `ispunct` wont eliminate the character. It wil just indicate if its a `punct` or no

Comment: @user, nothing in your code modifies `s`, so I'm not sure what you mean by "elimination of punctuation". As it stands, you're iterating over the string and printing characters, nothing more.

Comment: @user2474562  Also, ispunct wont eliminate the character. It wil just indicate if its a punct or no

Comment: But c is a reference to s. Hence any change in c reflects on s too. Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: `ispunct` does not do anything to what is passed to it. See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/ispunct.html) man page. It only returns 0 or non zero

Comment: `c` is a reference to one character in `s` for each iteration in your for loop.  What your for loop is saying is "for each character in `s`, reference that character via `c`", but that does not in any way affect `s`.

Comment: "If it's not a punctuation, let it get into the loop which contains the cout statement. " Isn't that what
if(!ispunct(c))
       {
           cout<<c;
       }
means?

Comment: Thanks. I'm clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why i don't really like the *auto* feature, auto in your case is a char and there is no elimination from the string.

LE: *ispunct* doesn't remove the character from the string, it doesn't even know (or care) that you have a *string*, it only returns true if the character is punctuation character or false if not, and based on that return the cout statement is executed with the character that is not punctuation or not executed for punctuation character.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I didn't quite get it right. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion with `auto` here.  It's a range-based for loop over a container of char.  What else would it be?

Comment: @AndreKostur well, the OP thought it's a reference to the whole string, anyway i'm not a big fan of _auto_, especially in educational code - but that's only my opinion.

Comment: @Zlatomir Well, of course if you don't know how a `for` loop works and what a `std::string` is, chances are you don't even get what a `char` is and where it should be written either.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is the entire string, so `cout<<s` sends the entire string to your output stream :\

Your second attempt works because you're sending individual characters to the stream.  In the first attempt though, you're sending the whole string for each character that exists in the string.  Count the number of non-punct characters in your string, then count the number of times the string was printed out ;)

Comment: Yup, I know I realized the number of punctuations and number of times the string printed were same. But isn't the whole string only hello world after the loop for elimination of punctuation is run?

Comment: No, the original string `s` stays intact.  Your loop allows `c` to see one character of `s` at a time, one character for each iteration in your loop, but nothing in your code modifies `s`, so anytime you `cout<<s`, you print the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

[`ispunct`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/ispunct.html) does not eliminate the character that is a `punct`. **It only returns `0` or `non-zero` to indicate
if it is `punct` or `no`.**

When you encounter a character that is not `punct`, it returns `0`. And you enter your `if`. You are printing `s` that is the whole string.

Whereas, with `cout<<c` you only print the character (which is non `punct`, since you are now in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

One more variant, using STL algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::back_inserter;
using std::copy_if;

int main()
{
    string s("hello world!..!.");
    string result = "";
    copy_if(begin(s), end(s), 
        back_inserter(result),
        [](char c){return !ispunct(c);}
    );
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

For real world code it's recommended to prefer suitable STL algorithms if available over a loop, because saying `copy_if` states your intent clearly, and does not focus on the individual steps to take. Whether or not it's better in this example I don't want to judge. But it's certainly good to keep this possibility in mind!

One more thing: It's generally regarded a bad thing to write `using namespace std`, because this can lead to name collisions when a future version of C++ introduces new keywords which you've already defined yourself in your own code. Either use the prefix `std::` all the time, or follow the way I've shown in my example, this keeps your code safe.